# ScrollView обрезает начало текста

Tags: android, xml, android-textview, android-scrollview

Я решил сделать показ стоки в TextView, который находится в HorizontalScrollView.

Если текст маленький, то он должен показываться по центру, а если он не влезает, то должна работать горизонтальная прокрутка.

**XML разметка**:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="45sp">

          <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:orientation="horizontal">

               <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/wordInfo_thisLanguage"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Слово"
                  android:textAlignment="center"
                  android:textSize="36sp"
                  android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
          </LinearLayout>
     </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Полную XML разметку можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/sashaqwert/scspeak/blob/0.8/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_word_info.xml).

Проблема заключается в том, что при длинном тексте программа обрезает начало текста, а в конце текста пустое место, которое равно длине обрезанного текста.
[image: Текст обрезан. (видно по переводам на другие языки)]
[image: В конце много пустого места]

Android 7.1 (API 25)

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему обрезается текст?

Comment: LinearLayout в данном случае лишний, его можно убрать. А на других версиях Андроида нормально работает?

Comment: @CoolMind наша других версиях тоже самое. Проверял на 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы маленький текст показывался **по центру**, а большой прокручивался, нужно поместить по центру экрана не TextView (не Layout с TextView), а сам **ScrollView**.

**XML разметка**:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordInfo_thisLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Слово"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: что за ширина в `sp`, для чего так указывать ширину?

Comment: @pavlofff в `sp` я указал высоту, чтобы `ScrollView` был именно такой высоты на всех устройствах. Можно указать `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас стоит выравнивание текста по центру. Убрал лишнее.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordInfo_thisLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:text="Слово поварповар авполавдпоавдлпо овдлжаоавдлпов ваповалдполд "/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Вместо `android:text` удобно использовать `tools:text`. В этом случае в окне preview вы увидите пример текста, а при запуске его не будет.

Comment: В таком случае маленький текст будет по левому краю, а не по центру